# 友人と as a subject

Tags: particle-が, subjects

A sentence from a blog whose host is temporarily absent from school:

> 実際に行動を起こすなら友人とがいい。

This sentence is not difficult to understand.

I was able to rule out the possibility of `がいい` here acting as a 副助詞 as in `見るがいい`. However, I feel unsure of myself to interpret `友人と` as the subject of this sentence, governing the `が` after it.

I've come across comparative expressions like `～と～とでは`, but this sentence above is my first time looking at something like `とが`. I cannot wrap my head around what constitutes a legitimate subject in Japanese.

Comment: Would you have difficulty with 〜からが and 〜までが, too?

Comment: @aguijonazo Thanks for bringing these two up since I have not had the chance to light upon them myself. I reckon I've yet to read enough _real_ Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some particles, such as から and まで, can form noun phrases.

> 熱海**まで**がＪＲ東日本で、その次の駅**から**がＪＲ東海です。

Though I might have given you the impression by my comment that と works in a similar way to them, that’s not quite the case. I think your sentence could be understood as an abbreviated version of the following, in which the nominalizer の, not と, is the head of the noun phrase.

> 実際に行動を起こすなら友人と（起こすの）がいい。

The original sentence doesn’t sound particularly informal. It sounds normal enough.